# What is the person who guards a parking area called?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

A parking area might have a person who stands at the entrance. You buy a ticket from them and the person lets you park your car in the parking area.

When you want to get out of parking area, you give the ticket to them and the person will check to make sure your car matches the ticket.

**What is that person called, for example, "a parking area (wo)man"?**

Comment: Most commonly, a **ticket machine**. ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They would usually be called a *parking attendant*. Sometimes '*car park attendant*' is also used in the UK.

There may be other job roles in the parking sector, such as *parking enforcement officers*, but the role you described doesn't sound like it involves anything more than an attendant.

Comment: Parking enforcement officers in the UK are very often called 'traffic wardens' and they are employed by the local government authority to patrol the streets of an area ensuring that vehicles are parked where they should be, and issue financial penalty notices ('tickets') if not. Nowadays in some towns and cities they also issue tickets for minor offences such as littering, antisocial behaviour, graffiti, etc.

Comment: what about "a valet"?

Comment: @Tom A valet is someone to whom you give your car keys, they get in your vehicle and find a parking space for you. Then they bring your vehicle back to you when you're done. They may even clean your car while you attend your event.

Comment: depending what else he does, he might be a parking / parking lot manager. But that implies he's also doing a lot more than just sitting in the ticket booth.

Comment: "Parking attendant" would be a likely term in the U.S., too.  Here we say "parking lot" rather than "car park", and "parking lot attendant" would be another possibility for the kind of person the question asks about.

Comment: Assuming it's a guy in a booth, and not a temporary folding chair type situation, I'd probably call them a security guard or a parking guard. With the assumption being that they do more than just sell parking passes.

Comment: Also, ["parking lot attendant"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=parking+lot+attendant)

Comment: @Tom Also somewhat confusingly, in the UK a ["valet"](https://nationalcareers.service.gov.uk/job-profiles/car-valet) may refer to somebody who carefully cleans your car to make it look new. In the US and Canada we'd call such a cleaner a "detailer".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you asked in your question is referred to as 'parking security' (in Australia, and in my experience), but what you described would probably be 'parking attendant' as others have mentioned.

Answer (score -5):

We call it "Valet" in our area. Like, some persons are dedicated to "Valet Parking", where a person gives the ticket and take the key and drives to the parking spot while owner of the car should only take the ticket and while departing the "valet" bring the car out. Then "Valet" is given some "tips(money)".

Note: I have a friend working in "Valet Parking".

Comment: What is "our area"? This could be important information for the OP to know which dialect of English this is valid for. From your style of writing, I'd guess South Asia?

Comment: OP is not describing a scenario where an exchange of keys occurs. The driver themself still parks the car.